# Angular material dialog isn't shown properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

The dialog is shown on the bottom of my page with a strange look and behaviour! [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)
Here are the versions am working with:

@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8,
 @angular/core": "^4.2.6"

I'm using bootstrap v3.7.x ( i was trying to use ng-bootstrap modal and turns out it doesn't work with bootstrap 3 any longer)

**my.component.html**

```
 <button md-button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openMyModal()">OPEN</button>
```

**my.component.ts:**

```
import {MdDialog} from '@angular/material';
import {MyModal} from "./myModal.component"
@Component({
  templateUrl: "./my.component.html"
})
    export class My {
      constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

    openMyModal():void {
        const modalInstance = this.dialog.open(MyModal);
      }
    }
```

**myModal.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

        @Component({
          template: `<div class="modal-body">
                          Modal content Here
                          </div>`
        })
        export class MyModal {
          constructor(

    public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<MyModal>) {}
    }
```

[How the html of the modal is displayed on botton of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLCY2.png)

Comment: Did you add your dialog component under `entryComponents` in `NgModule`?

Comment: Also, can you share your error log, if there's any?

Comment: @Edric yeah i did! entryComponents: [PaymentModal] !  i get no error! i just get the html on the botton of my page not in a modal shape! i'll post a screenshot in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix this theme by importing this in my main styles.scss

@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Angular core themes. Without that some material components act weird. I have a custom theme for my app and I import in my css file.

```
@import '../../../node_modules/@angular/material/theming';
```

Comment: Where should i import this? in styles.scss ? i tried that nothing changed!

Comment: try encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in main component.

Comment: I get there two warnings in my console however and i suspect they may have something to do with this weird behaviour! "Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected" and " Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly."